# How can.Obamacare implode?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, affordable-care-act

Trump says 'let obamacare implode'.

He says it like it will happen but will it? In the next 4 years? Maybe this is opinion based but then i ask: what possible ways are there for it to implode?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't possibly know what Trump means with his Tweets.

Comment: Thats not the question either

Comment: You are quoting Trump and asking us to to interpret what he means by 'implode'. This site can't become a "Trump Tweet Translator" unfortunately. For one, we couldn't keep up. But more importantly, even his own administration often doesn't know what he's implying with his tweets. We can't possibly know.

Comment: Health care, with or without ACA, might end up imploding because of [metabolic syndrome related diseases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmC4Rm5cpOI).

Comment: @blip - the assertion that Obamacare can implode is in no way unique to Trump and precedes his tweet (and probably his candidacy).

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/obamacare-2017-insurer-exits-from-states-map-2017-4... obamacare isn't going to completely 'implode', but portions of some states already have no insurance provider for obamacare, and that is due to expand in 2018. Obamacare in its current form has proven to be unprofitable for insurance companies, in some circumstances. I disagree that this is off topic, as obamacare is definitely the result of politics gone bad.